# What is the default user and password for Elasticsearch 7.8.0?

Tags: elasticsearch

What's is the default username and password for Elasticsearch 7.8.0? It's asking this on 9200 port. Tried these (username pass):

- elastic [no pass]
- elastic elastic
- without entering anything
- elastic changeme
- elastic password
- user password

OS: Windows 10 x64, installed ES with MSI installer from its website.

yml file:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: LAPTOP-1C4GVFSU
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

[image: username pass]
[image: C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\7.8.0]
[image: C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\7.8.0\bin]

Comment: @Bhavya Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow default username password isn't working. I had to set the password on CMD by

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive

bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

The `interactive` parameter prompts new password for the users, whereas `auto` generates them for you.

Answer (score 3):

try the following command

```
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

it generates new password for user "elastic"

Answer (score 1):

**Username is `elastic` and Password is `password`**

1. If you are trying to debug [Elasticsearch Source Code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch), then after running `./gradlew :run`, ES starts building and running.

Once the service has started, run this curl command from another window :

```
curl -u elastic:password localhost:9200
```

After which add the username and password as mentioned above. To know more about this refer [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

2. It may also be possible, that you have only added the `xpack.security.enabled` setting to the `ES_PATH_CONF/elasticsearch.yml` file.

After which if you try to hit `localhost:9200`, then it will ask for username and password (as you have enabled security feature). But since you have not set up username and password, so it will throw `security_exception` (when incorrect username and password are entered).

So, for that, run `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`, and set the username and password.

Refer to this documentation for [Setting built-in user and password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords)

Comment: i cant login with elastic:password
If i enter them. It shows same form with "this site says: security"
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}

Comment: C:\Users\etosu>curl -u elastic:password localhost:9200
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}

Comment: @emretosunkaya have u tried to use elasticsearch-setup-passwords util to generate/set password for the inbuilt user of elastic, by running this `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`

Comment: @emretosunkaya are u trying to run ES source code ? (b/c only there username and password are asked --> for which u must know the default ones) . Otherwise, if u have just installed elasticsearch, then `security_exception` will come when either your username and password is incorrect, which u have set in the interactive mode by using above command .

Comment: @emretosunkaya are u trying to run and debug ES source code OR just running ES service ?

Comment: @emretosunkaya refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html to set built in user and password for elasticsearch.

Feel free to ask further as recently only, I have bumped onto a similar issue, and my issue was resolved :)

Comment: @emretosunkaya please go through my updated answer and do let me know if your issue is resolved or not :)

Comment: ok i set up by bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive

but default pass didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/nginx/` for `nginx.con` files and nginx `passwd` file.
ElasticSearch is using simple Nginx passwd file and basic authentication for default instance.

Answer (score 0):

If trying locally and want to run without entering default username and password try disabling it by changing below config line under file `config/elasticsearch.yml`

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

getting this error on disabling xpack.security.enabled = false
and got an error like this:

SSL connection to https://10.110.45.178:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty failed: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.110.45.178 found
Please check the elasticsearch SSL settings under xpack.security.http.ssl.